# R, Add binary columns based on values in existing column

Tags: r

Beginner in R and looking to avoid unnecessary copy+pasting...

I have a data frame with a numeric column. I would like to create binary columns based on the values in the numeric column.

I know the tedious approach would be to copy+paste the following and manually add the different values:

```
DataFrame$NewCol1 <- as.numeric(DataFrame$ExistingCol == 1);

DataFrame$NewCol2 <- as.numeric(DataFrame$ExistingCol == 2);
```

Would a "for" loop be able to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
model.matrix(~factor(DataFrame$ExistingCol))[,-1]
```

Comment: Sorry for delay, this worked for me. But I actually found a better solution as well. 

library(mlr)
df <- createDummyFeatures(df, cols = "df$Col")